# Proc import with excelcs and xlsx in sas

Tags: sas

I am trying to import the excel file with .xlsx with DBMS = excelcs and it works
However when I try the same on another system it doesnt work and I have to change the DBMS to xlsx.

what could be the problem.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very helpful to the rest of us.  What is the exact error message you get?  Please also post your code.

Comment: I use the general import procedue.
the excel file is .xlsx and i write DBMS=excelcs
it works on one system and when I run it on an another system it says: 
"filename.xlsx" doesnt exist. 
so I change the dbms from excelcs to xlsx, then it works.. but some of the variables datatypes got converted from numeric to char.

Comment: You mean you use proc import?  Please post proc import code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one of the systems is not a PC Files Server machine.

See: http://support.sas.com/kb/41/060.html

If you're using EG -- I'd suggest to use the built in import wizard.